# functional dependency confusion

Tags: database, relational-database, database-schema

i had a question about a funcitonal dependency that i dont understand.

[table is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyBo0.png)

i for the life of me cant understand why
{course,quarter,section_number}--->{faculty}

is a dependency . the course column throws me off because there all different and dont match the quarter column. for example , fall 2013 has 2 different values in cs520 and cs 422. i thought that fall 2013 had to have the same values? if i remmeber the definition of a FD is Functional dependency says that if two tuples have same values for attributes A1, A2,..., An, then those two tuples must have to have same values for attributes B1, B2, ..., Bn. im sooo confused by this FD lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your FD means is that for any combination of course, quarter and section number, there's one particular faculty member assigned.  You seem to be confusing that with a hypothetical FD `quarter -> course`, which would require that each quarter have only one course value.

From the data, I can see that `quarter -> faculty` doesn't hold, since both *C. Sun* and *E. Kang* are associated with *Fall 2013*.  `course -> faculty` does hold for the given data - *CS520* appears twice and is associated only with *C. Sun*, every other course appears only once.  Since `course` is a determinant for faculty, any superset of columns that includes course is also determining.

You can think of functional dependencies like functions in programming.  Given the value(s) for the column(s) on the left-hand side as input, can you deterministically return the matching value(s) of the column(s) on the right-hand side?  If yes, you have an FD.  You don't have to use all the values on the left-hand side, but like in programming, minimal functional dependencies are important.